# pandas - select group from groupby(by=[group1, group2])

Tags: python, pandas

I'm grouping dataframe by 2 groups `native-country` and `salary`, but output on `hours-per-week` is too large to find specific country.

```
df.groupby(by=['native-country', 'salary'])['hours-per-week']
```

How to select group by country name, e.g. 'Japan' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a `groupby` at all if you're not trying to perform any aggregations/transformations? Just do:

```
df.query("'native-country' == 'Japan'")\
  .loc[:, ["native_country", "salary", "hours-per-week"]]
```

Comment: Well, guess that would be more relevant. Absolutely forgot about that possibility with 5 questions on groupby in row ("To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail")

Comment: Happens to all of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   newdf = ddf.groupby('country').**size()/all()/count()/...**

   result = newdf.filter(lambda x : True if x.country == 'japan' else False)lt

   print result
```